# asp.net mvc master detail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-detail

I want to create a web page for order entry using ASP.NET MVC- Entity Framework. This page contains Order and Order Entry information. For each Order, I can have multiple Order details. If you know how to do this Master/Detail with ASP.NET MVC-Entity Framework please let me know. The user should be able to enter new order with one or many order detail. this should be on one single page

Plz could u provide a working example

Answer (score 5):

Your question is pretty general and vague but here's a [sample code](http://kenneththorman.blogspot.com/2010/06/aspnet-mvc-20-master-detail-views.html) and a [followup](http://kenneththorman.blogspot.com/2010/12/aspnet-mvc-master-detail-list-view-with.html) you may start playing with. If you encounter some specific problems implementing it don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: in simple word How can I Provide a CRUD operation for two relating Table  For example Order and Order Detail    All Example all sample only make CRUD For one table

Comment: @MVCGUY, are you talking about SQL tables? In the example I provided there are 3 SQL tables: users, projects and project_bids (mapping table)

Comment: hops I didn't notice the first link I think it will help me thanks a lot

Comment: Could any one provide Master-detail CRUD sample for two table for example 1- Order: with OrderID (int, key), OrderDate,CustomerID,Notes 2-OrderDetail: with OrderDetail(int, key), OrderID ,ItemID,Quantity,Price

Comment: @MVCGUY, did you encounter some specific problems adapting the suggested sample to your scenario?

Comment: I want a view like this and that enable me to add update delete Instructor and Add edit delete Course Taught

http://www.asp.net/media/801489/WindowsLiveWriter_TheEntityFramewor.NETGettingStartedPart4_C24C_Image05.png

I Hope that I clarify my question
Your Provided example for displaying data only and it is not like my case

Comment: @MVCGUY, yes but what prevents you from adapting it? Simply add a column to the table containing the required links, implement the corresponding controller actions, ...

Comment: I am a beginner i wana a working example to learn from it ,I think it is not simple as you think

Answer (score 3):

I have [blogged](http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-i.html) about creating master detail form using asp.net mvc. it contains sample code to download

Answer (score 2):

[Sample master detain project with MVC 3 and EF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Detail-CRUD-Operations-fbe935ef)